# Flutter GestureDetector onLongPress Using 3 fingers

Tags: flutter

What should I do to make Flutter GestureDetector onLongPress work on 3 finger taps?
GestureDetector onLongPress detects 1 finger touch by default I want it to detect 3 or 4 fingers

Comment: most likely you need `RawGestureDetector` used with [MultiTapGestureRecognizer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/MultiTapGestureRecognizer-class.html)

Comment: what is your goal? you want emit a function only when user use three fingers for long pressing a widget? or you want emit that function also for 1 and 2 finger long presses?

Comment: I want to issue a function when user uses 1 or more than 1 finger to long press a widget

Comment: pskink, MultiTapGestureRecognizer doesn't seem to be suitable for doing what I want.

Comment: I'm new to Flutter and I'd appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: not suitable? you want multi touch and the docs say: "Recognizes taps on a per-pointer basis.

MultiTapGestureRecognizer considers each sequence of pointer events that could constitute a tap independently of other pointers: For example, down-1, down-2, up-1, up-2 produces two taps, on up-1 and up-2."

Comment: Can you show an example how can I use it?